# Enable/fix workspace-switcher overaly thumbnails in Gnome 3.20

Tags: gnome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I've got Gnome 3.20 running with the "Workspace Grid" extension. Everything works well, except when pressing ctrl + alt + [arrow] to navigate my workspaces, the resulting overaly doesn't actually show what's on the workspace. If I go into the Activities are, the workspace thumbnails are displayed as they should be.

Here's what the overlay looks like currently (notice that the overaly is totally blank in each box): 
[image: Picture of blank overlays (where there should be thumbnails of what's currently on the screen]

Here's what it should look like:
[image: Picture of correct overlays (where there are thumbnails of what's currently on the screen]

I currently use the "Workspace Grid" plugin, also.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Gnome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one hasn't noticed, the said issue has been unsolved for the past two years to this answered date, according to [this issue #4](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/issues/4) on GitHub. The description is also very much alike:

> If one tries to switch workspaces using the Gnome "hot corner" then one can see all workspaces with all the windows respectively opened in them. I would like a similar display here, while switching workspaces, rather than just a grid of boxes [...]

The current maintainer, zakkak, seems to be aware of this issue from before and even quoted another project that had similar feature.

> [This one](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extension-workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails) seems more related to what we want to achieve.

The implementation however, seems to be incomplete:

> I have tried implementing it but I don't know how to make it centre aligned. Anyone who wants to try and fix/improve it can find the code in https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/tree/thumbnails. It currently displays both the switcher and the thumbnails for testing purposes.

Several contributors had tried testing the implementation and latest attempt to this date was recorded in early-2016, which noted the limitation in [this issue #23](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/issues/23).

> **Incorrect grid scaling** #23
>
> As mentioned in [#4](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/issues/4)
>
> screenshot from 2016-01-16 18-09-04 (omitted to avoid [hotlinking](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking))
>
> Note that this is using the 'thumbnails' branch.

Note that this answer:

- intends to quote relevant information found in the linked resources;
- assumes that OP is *not* aware of the issue being discussed on GitHub;
- otherwise is useful for users who are affected by the same issue.

**Disclaimer** I do *not* use GNOME and *not* involved with the project.

**TL;DR** Try out the 'thumbnails' branch, if you haven't. Review the code and suggest improvements at the project repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This extension works fine to me in Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome 3.28.3,

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/

I installed manually following the step showed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g25yTWiuUcg)!.

Comment: It is good practice to give key information in the answer instead of an external link (so that if the external link goes down not everything is lost)